# Createjs, how do you extend the class of an Animate CC library object?

Tags: typescript, createjs, animate-cc

I am in the process of converting a large flash application to canvas using Typescript and I am having trouble using classes to extend library objects.

Using a class library for buttons,

```
class BtnClass { 
    constructor(el: createjs.MovieClip) {
        el.addEventListener("mouseover", MouseOverHandler.bind(el));
    }
}
```

If I have an object placed on stage in Animate CC, I could use this class by adding the actions in frame for export and all works well,

```
Btn1 = new BtnClass(this.buttons.btn1_mc);
```

But I cannot get this to work for dynamically placed library objects.

I get an error when trying to extend my object with this class on a library object that is not placed on the Animate CC stage.

```
var libraryObject = new lib.btn2_mc();
var dynamicButton = createjs.extend(new BtnClass(libraryObject), libraryObject);
currentElement.addChild(dynamicButton);
```

Error: Argument of type 'BtnClass' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => any'. Type 'BtnClass' provides no match for the signature '(): any'.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am extending the createjs component in the following way and its works. Please try let me know if you have any issues

```
class BtnClass extends (lib.btn2_mc as { new(): any; }) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `extend` method takes classes as parameters, not instances.

```
createjs.extend(BtnClass, lib.btn2_mc);
```

It then returns the prototype, which you can append methods on to. You can then promote the methods from the super class, giving you access to the prototype methods if you override them. See the EaselJS classes for specific usages.

Not sure it will solve your problem, but at least its the correct syntax.